# phonegap offline sync with images

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I searched for similar question, but didn't find exact answer to my question.

I'm building phonegap application for iOS which will have online/offline sync functionality.
I want to sync offline SQLite database with JSON data from server every time application will launch. I think It can work slow when user will launch app for the first time (100% of data will be fetched), because sync function will have to download over 50 images...

I don't even know if appstore will approve solution like that.

What is the best solution for that kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the request. For example 10 images for each request. Like so, the user will be able to see the images before all of it are fetched.